# "Error while loading shared libraries" raised when linking boost library, except I cannot use root access to fix it

Tags: c++, boost, shared-libraries, root

I am trying to run some code on my school's super computer, running on Ubuntu.
That code happens to require the timer library in boost.

So I uploaded the boost 1.71.0 repository, built it succesfully.

Then I built it with the following command (successfully)
g++ -g src/foo.cpp -o run/foo -I ../boost_1_71_0/ -L ../boost_1_71_0/stage/lib/ -lboost_timer -fopenmp -std=c++11

Then when I try to run the file, this happens:
Error while loading shared libraries: libboost_timer.so.1.71.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I scrolled through several forum discussions, and apparently running the following command should update the library path and fix everything:
sudo /sbin/ldconfig -v
But since I have no root access, I cannot run it.
I'm looking for a workaround that doesn't involve any sudoing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run your program by ensuring `../boost_1_71_0/stage/lib/` is in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` so the dynamic loader knows where to search for the Boost shared libraries. Run your program as follows, assuming the Boost libraries are located at `../boost_1_71_0/stage/lib/` relative from the directory where your program is located on disk.

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=../boost_1_71_0/stage/lib/ ./program
```

Comment: One caveat here is that there are times when LD_LIBRARY_PATH will be ignored for security reasons. But, if the OP can't become root, I don't believe it's possible for the OP to encounter these situations.